# SET INDEX on a reference name inside SELECT statement for parent SELECT

Tags: mysql

I want to have FULLTEXT INDEX on a reference named `data`

```
SELECT `data` FROM (
   SELECT `body` as `data` FROM `table1`
   UNION
   SELECT `text` as `data` FROM `table2`
) as `search`
```

We assume that two SQL statements w/ union create a virtual table from where `data` is selected, how to make a `data` behave like fulltext index for later using `MATCH() AGAINST()` in top first `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can create view and fulltext index for it: [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can make multiple statements, create a temporary table, with all the indexes you need, insert into it and then run your query.